# Bootstrap изменение размера элемента

Tags: html, bootstrap

На страницах при выборе различных режимов появляются блоки с содержимым.
К примеру, один выглядит следующим образом:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: black">
    <div col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6>content...</div>
    <div col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6>content...</div>
    <div col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6>content...</div>
    <div col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6>content...</div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что при узком экране получается 4 столбца xs-6, и в итоге 2 последних оказываются за пределами родительского блока. Плюс к этому, следующие блоки отрисовываются прямо над этими столбцами.

Как в этом случае изменять высоту родителя?

Comment: А какого поведения вы хотите добиться? Сейчас у вас для xs 2 колонки, для всего, что больше — 4 [вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/98mzs5c4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: black">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 m-d">content...</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 m-d">content...</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 m-d">content...</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 m-d">content...</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.m-d {
    display: block;
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
 }
</style>
```

Попробуйте так...